# Extraction of daily data from multiple NetCDF files

Tags: qgis, raster, r, terra

I am trying to extract daily weather data from NetCDF files'(in total 4 files). Each file has 25 years of data and size approximately 1gb. I tried extracting data by using below method but it did not work in the last. When I ran the last line of code for extraction, R showed error as follows : "Error: std::bad_alloc".

I saw one of the reason for this error could be unavailable memory. Could you tell me what else could go wrong and how can I make my code more efficient as on internet?

```
 rm(list= ls())
    setwd("U:/my_storage/Data_for_thesis/weather_data_IMD")



#------write a list to  import all the files ending with .nc to import in R ------#

tmin_files = list.files('tmin/',pattern='*.nc',full.names=TRUE)

print(tmin_files)



   #---------------------- Read all the files using --------------------------#


                           #---- Second Method -----#

# Read all files using 'rast' function from 'terra' and store them in a list
tmin_rasters <- lapply(tmin_files, rast)
print(tmin_rasters)
class(tmin_rasters)


   #---------------- Cropping data to an area of Interest --------------------#


# read Vector data file 

VDSA_districts <- st_read("U:/my_storage/Data_for_thesis/DLD_shp/dld_modified_2.shp")
st_crs(VDSA_districts) <- 4326
st_transform(VDSA_districts, crs = st_crs(tmin_rasters[[1]])) 


# crop a raster layer to the specific area of interest

cropped_rain <- terra::crop(tmin_rasters, VDSA_districts)

# Crop each raster individually using lapply
cropped_tmin <- lapply(tmin_rasters, function(r) terra::crop(r, VDSA_districts))

cropped_tmin[[1]]


    #--------- Extract raster values from raster layer for vector data ----------#


                  #--------- Using Terra package --------#

# Extracting to polygon

# first convert VDSA_district (an sf object) to a SpatVector.

VDSA_districts_sv <- vect(VDSA_districts)

# let's extract weather data for each district
  
tmin_district<- lapply(cropped_tmin, function(r) terra::extract(r, VDSA_districts_sv))
```